# Rails 4.2 "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)" error when passing object to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)" error when trying to reference an object passed to a partial.

Here is the **show.html.erb** fragment which invokes the partial. I have numbered a couple of the lines here to help explain. Line 1 runs fine and the generated link works. Line 2 fails:

```
<% if @bucket.tree_id %>
  <%= link_to Tree.find(@bucket.tree_id).name, Tree.find(@bucket.tree_id) %>   [1]
  <%= render "shared/bucket_as_table", object: Tree.find(@bucket.tree_id), as: :t %>   [2]
<% end %>
```

Here is the line in **shared/_bucket_as_table.html.erb** where the partial fails:

```
<h1><%= t.name%></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah! So I checked the docs again (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html). Apparently I need the key "partial" as part of the call:

```
<%= render partial: "shared/bucket_as_table", object: Tree.find(@bucket.tree_id), as: :t %>
```

instead of

```
<%= render "shared/bucket_as_table", object: Tree.find(@bucket.tree_id), as: :t %>
```

While it is always included in the official docs, I don't see this in Michael Hartl's book (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#code-signup_errors_updated) or explained properly in the **The Rails 4 Way** ([https://www.amazon.com/Rails-Way-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Ruby/dp/0321944275](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321944275), p. 327). So if someone can explain that to me, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing form object as local:

```
<%= render "shared/bucket_as_table", locals: {t: Tree.find(@bucket.tree_id)} %>
```

And in `shared/_bucket_as_table.html.erb`

`<h1><%= t.name%></h1>`

Update:

You can replace `:t` as `'t'`

```
<% @tree = Tree.find(@bucket.tree_id) %>
<%= render "shared/bucket_as_table", object: @tree, as: 't' %>
```

You can refer document at [partial](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

Comment: Yes sorry I tried that alternative syntax. I didn't mention it in the original question to keep it brief. Rails docs say they are the same: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

Comment: @MSC I've just updated my answer, you can check it again.

Comment: Yes, that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in your object "Tree". Check if there is a method named "name" of if do you extends or compose some class with this method.

Comment: I have used t.name with no problems on other pages. If I changed my partial to read <h1><%= t %></h1> the problem persists. But I checked the Tree model and controller and found nothing worrying.